# Find max value in a Flink DataStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a DataStream of Tuple2<String, Integer>.  I want to find the max of field `f1`, preferably without doing a keyBy().  Is that possible in Flink?

One "hack" I came up with:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> input;  // Initialized somewhere
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> maxEntry = 
                        input.map(entry -> new Tuple3(entry.f0, entry.f1, "foo"))
                             .keyBy(2)
                             .maxBy(1)
                             .map(entry -> new Tuple2(entry.f1, entry.f1));
```

Doing the intermediate `map()` and `keyBy()` seems to me wasteful/inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Does the DataStream contain 1 element after this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, which is still hacky, but less so

```java
input.keyBy(e -> "foo").maxBy(1)
```

but keep in mind that

1. Keying by a constant reduces the effective parallelism to 1 (which is fine in this case, as you need to process every event in the same place to find a global maximum).
2. `KeyedStream#maxBy` will be removed from Flink in the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651834/2000823 for more about that.